# setter does on execute on parsing params

Tags: spring, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I want to create an object of TradePost Domain. And For data fields I just pass params that i get by default in grails action.

But on parse that params map in constructor as per the grails documentation and it should call setters for all these attributes in params.
But in my case setStatus enum does not execute.

```
class TradePost {

    long id
    StatusEnum status    //Used to get the status of post i.e Buy or Sell
    String location
    String currency

    public void setStatus(String key)
    {
        println "cAlledgggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"+key
        this.status=StatusEnum.getStatus(key)
    }
}
```

And call that i make to create object

```
user.tradePosts.add(new TradePost(params))
```

it should call the setter of status property but does not call.

Comment: Just making an educated guess but I suspect it's because the method signature of your implementation does not match what is being called. e.g setStatus(<StatusEnum>) vs setStatus(<String>)

Comment: Sir in params Map is of type <String,String>. So i will get "status":"value".For conversion I am using setter.

Comment: Yes, I realize that however, there is much more going on than simple property assignment. You do have Grails working to make sure data types are cast correctly for you. I suspect it's casting it to `StatusEnum`.